# Using Groovy comparison operators with Date objects

Tags: datetime, date, groovy, operators, gdk

I'm investigating an issue and ran across some suspicious code involving comparison of Date instances using comparison operators. e.g.

```
    def stamp = ... //Date
    def offset = ... //Integer
    def d = new Date(stamp.time + offset)
    if (d < new Date()) {
        ...
    }
```

[This](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-pg10255.html) resource indicates the above is equivalent to the following

```
    def stamp = ... //Date
    def offset = ... //Integer
    def d = new Date(stamp.time + offset)
    if (d.compareTo(new Date()) < 0) {
        ...
    }
```

However, the [GDK documentation on Dates](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN0545-Dates) only has examples comparing dates using `compareTo`, `before`, and `after` and I seem to recall specifically avoiding using the comparison operators on Dates due to an experience with unexpected results.  Are the above two code examples indeed equivalent (that is, can I safely use comparison operators on Dates in Groovy, or should I only use `compareTo`, `before`, and `after`)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Well if you plug them into the handy GroovyConsole they have the same result.

If I understand the question correctly:

```
def stamp = Date.parse("MM/dd/yyyy","02/02/2010")
def offset = 1213123123
def d = new Date(stamp.time+offset)
if(d < new Date() ) { 
    println "before"
}
if(d.compareTo(new Date()) < 0) { 
    println "before"
}
```

Prints "before" twice

If I switched the stamp date to 2011 lets say it would not print.

Comment: I did experiment with this in the GroovyConsole, but am afraid I might be missing some corner case involving the different components of a Date.

Comment: how to know two date value is the same ?  is it just like this d.compareTo(new Date()) ==0 ) ? thankx